# Using string split with tab characters in PowerShell 1.0

Tags: powershell, split

I'm processing tab-separated text file (ANSI) in PowerShell 1.0, and for some reason I can't split text in the file into multiple fields using the `split` function. The code below always returns 1 although there are five values separated by tab in each line of the file.

```
$f = get-content ‘users.txt’
foreach ($line in $f)
{
   $fields = $line.split('\t')
   $fields.count | Out-Host
}
```

I tested split with other separators like pipe, comma and it worked without problems.

Comment: Show us the contents of your text file, is everything on one line?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're using the wrong escape character for the tab. Try this instead:

```
$f = Get-Content "Users.txt"

foreach ($line in $f) {
    $fields = $line.Split("`t")
    $fields.Count | Out-Host
}
```

Comment: It works, thanks. Not really clear what was the reason behind using this type of escape character instead of regular one.

Comment: Then you should read the help for about_quoting_rules and about_escape_characters.

Comment: @kirill_l - because \ is used in paths in windows, so paths will have to be specified like `c:\\windows` if \ were escape character. In a scripting environment like Powershell, paths are used often and hence the need.

Answer (score 1):

```
(Get-Content -LiteralPath C:\temp\Users.txt) | ForEach-Object {$_.Split("`t")} | Set-Content -Path C:\temp\Results.txt
```